# Problem about clocks that gain $2$, $6$ and $12$ minutes per hour respectively

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Three old clocks, whose hour hands are missing, have minute hands which all run fast. Clock P, Q and R gain 2, 6 and 12 minutes per hour respectively. They start at midday with all three minutes hands pointing to 12. Find the number of hours late when all three hands show the same number of minutes?

An olympiad student asked me this problem but I am struggling to find an elementary solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $h$ be the required number of hours.

Then $h$ is the least positive real number such that, mod $60$, we have
$$62h \equiv 66h \equiv 72h$$
Restated in terms of divisibility, we get
$$60|4h\;\;\text{and}\;\;60|6h$$
which simplifies to
$$15|h\;\;\text{and}\;\;10|h$$
Hence, since we want the least $h$, it follows that $h$ is the LCM of $10$ and $15$, so $h = 30$.

Notes:

- If $x,y,z$ are real numbers, the notation $x \equiv y\;(\text{mod}\;z)$ means $x-y = nz$, for some integer $n$.$\\[2pt]$

  If $x,y$ are real numbers, the notation $x|y$ means $y=nx$, for some integer $n$.

Comment: Same question here: Who says the hand movement is integral? i.e. what if they move continuously rather than tick?

Comment: Agreed. Although $h$ turns out to be a positive integer, the initial restriction should only be that $h$ is a positive real number. In light of that, I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 5):

The first minute hand ticks $62$ times in an hour, and the second one ticks $66$ times in an hour. The difference between the first two clocks is therefore $4$ ticks per hour. How long does it take before this difference is a multiple of $60$ ticks (which is what it means that they show the same)? Do the same between the second and third.

So now you know that the first two clocks align every $x$ hours, and the last two clocks align every $y$ hours. How often does this mean that the two alignments... align?

Comment: But do the watches tick or do they move continuously?

Comment: @einpoklum I'm thinking of it as ticking, but it doesn't really matter. Change "$4$ ticks per hour" into "$24^\circ$ per hour", and you get the same answer.

Comment: @einpoklum In a sense, the numbers 2, 6 and 12 are too nice. It does not matter if it is discrete or continuous. I propose the following problem. Clock P gains $\gamma$ minutes per hour, clock Q gains $e$ minutes per hour, and clock R gains $\pi$ minutes per hour. Here $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant, $e=\exp(1)$ is the base of the natural logarithm, and $\pi$ is the ratio between circumference and diameter for a circle. Now if each clock ticks, with positions that are the precise multiples of $6^\circ$, when will they again coincide? Then with uniform continuous motions - problem!